# How to transfer goods via airports/aircrafts?

Tags: openttd

I have airport, there is a plane which was re-fitted for moving goods. In 2-3 tiles from airport I have loading bay, where goods are available.

How to load goods to aircraft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The airport as well as the Loading Bay should have the same name i.e. they should be part of the same combined station

This is called a **Feeder Service**. To set this up you should either

- Build the cargo bay one tile next to the airport and they will automatically be assigned the same name and will share cargo. This will enable your aircrafts to load the cargo.
- Sometimes its not possible to build stations so close. Instead, you should Ctrl + left click while placing a station and you'll get a pop-up asking you to select which station it should be combined with. There’s a limit for the maximum area a combined station can cover. By default the limit is 12×12 tiles.

You can only have one dock and/or airport in any given station at a time, unlike road vehicle and train stations.

You can remove a component of a combined station using the dynamite tool which will remove just that individual station, not the overall thing. The exception to this is train stations, where dynamiting one part of a train station will remove all of them (or not, if there are trains in any of them).

Do check out the wiki because this is explained much better there.

[**Combining Stations wiki**](https://wiki.openttd.org/Stations#Combining_stations) 
[**Feeder Service wiki**](https://wiki.openttd.org/Feeder_service)

Comment: A "feeder service" is when you user another vehicle (like a truck) to bring goods to the main vehicle (like a plane). In OP's case it will probably be enough to extend the airport station by joining the loading bay, so that united station catchment area will reach the industry. In this case, the type of "extender" station does not matter, it can be a truck loading bay, a helipad or a train station, as long as it covers the goods source.